# VirtualBox "Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted" after clonezilla retore on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, clonezilla, p2v

I've cloned my Physical machine of Windows 10 using clonezilla.

I've created a new VM with a blank disk and restored the clonezilla disk image without any error.

After reboot (and remove of the clonezilla iso) the virtualbox ends with the famous :
Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted

I've tried to use disk2VHD to build a VHD disk image and use this disk image as the only drive of a new VM and....
no change : Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted

While my Physical machine can reboot without any problem.

After checking box "**enable EFI**" on system tab setting the boot ends up with :
A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped.
For help, please see the Community section on https://www.virtualbox.org or your support contract. Please provide the contents of the log file VBox.log and the image file VBox.png, which you can find in the /root/VirtualBox VMs/Disk2VHD/Logs directory, as well as a description of what you were doing when this error happened. Note that you can also access the above files by selecting Show Log from the Machine menu of the main VirtualBox window.
Press OK if you want to power off the machine or press Ignore if you want to leave it as is for debugging. Please note that debugging requires special knowledge and tools, so it is recommended to press OK now.

I do not find any valuable solution as most of "Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted" references ends up with very simple issues as no OS installed which no my case.

If you have any suggestion or explanation on why the disk does not boot...

Answer (score 1):

After checking box "enable EFI" on system tab setting.

I recieved this message :

A critical error has occurred while running the virtual machine and the machine execution has been stopped. For help, please see the Community section on https://www.virtualbox.org or your support contract. Please provide the contents of the log file VBox.log and the image file VBox.png, which you can find in the /root/VirtualBox VMs/Disk2VHD/Logs directory, as well as a description of what you were doing when this error happened. Note that you can also access the above files by selecting Show Log from the Machine menu of the main VirtualBox window. Press OK if you want to power off the machine or press Ignore if you want to leave it as is for debugging. Please note that debugging requires special knowledge and tools, so it is recommended to press OK now.

I click on ignore and ...

Tada !!!

It boot at last...